# angular js how to demove default 0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/726GH.png)

#### Sum of two Numbers using AngularJS

#### Using Double Negation

First Number: 
        Second Number: 
        Sum:

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/726GH.png

Comment: i dont want to see 0 as default

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS, by default, treats uninitialized models as `null`. So, in your case, `a` and `b` are both `null`.

That's why:

```
null - -null // {{ a -- b }} is {{ a - -b }} actually
```

will result in 0.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will covers your requirement. Thank you.

```js
var app = angular.module('demo', []);
app.controller('mainController', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
 $scope.testfunction = function(value) {
    return value>0 ?value:'';
  }  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="demo">
<div ng-controller="mainController as mainControl">
<img src="https://angularjs.org/img/AngularJS-large.png" height="50px" weight="50px"/>
<h3>Sum of two Numbers using AngularJS</h3>
<div>
     <h3>Using Double Negation</h3>
    First Number: <input type="text" ng-model="a" />
    Second Number: <input type="text" ng-model="b" />
    Sum:<input type="number" value='{{testfunction(a--b)}}' >       
</div></div>
</html>
```